# Definition: expressions that can be evaluated versus those that can't

Tags: computability, symbolic-computation

Suppose I have an expression $y + f(x)$, and I know $y \in \mathbb R, x \in   X$ and $f$ is an arbitrary function from $X$ to the reals.

If I know $y$ and $x$ but don't know $f$, I can't evaluate the expression $y + f(x)$. At least, not completely.

But once I know $f$, (say $f(z) = z^2$), then I can evaluate the expression $y + f(x)$.

Is there a name for the difference between these two circumstances?

Comment: In maths, there is no such instance where you can not evaluate a function. At he very least, I can always say that the evaluation of $f$ at $x$ is $f(x)$. Actually, I do not really see in what context your interrogation arises. Is there a context where this matters?

Comment: @Suzet That is not true. You can easily define a relation, for which you can prove that it is a function, but that you cannot prove any of its values.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft What does "to prove a value" mean? Is my sentence "I can always say that the evaluation of $f$ at $x$ is $f(x)$" wrong? :o

Comment: @Suzet As having a function $f:X\to\{0,1\}$ but for a given $x\in X$ you cannot prove whether $f(x)=0$ is true or false and whether $f(x)=1$ is true or false.

Comment: Right, but if for any reason I need to consider the evaluation of $f$ at $x$, that I can always do it, by calling this number $f(x)$, whether it equals $0$ or $1$ does not matter. Conceptually, there is no problem with this. Well however, I think that it is indeed not what the OP @alexpghayes is looking for. I'll let someone else give a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the terminology from predicate logic. An expression such as $x + f(y)$ is called a *term*.   In this particular term there are several *free variables* (e.g. $x$ and $y$ at least, and also $f$ if we view that as a variable for a function).  If we replace the free variables by *constants* (also known sometimes as *parameters*), so that no free variables remain, the term is then a *closed term*.    A term that has one or more free variables is called an *open term*.

In the usual framework of predicate logic, each closed term with parameters from a model $M$ denotes a particular element of the model $M$. Not only do we need the model to have parameters to substitute for the variables, we also need the model to give meaning to symbols such as $+$ that appear in the term.

Answer (score 0):

The following is informal, but sufficient for my purposes.

The key thing to understand is the difference between an *expression* and a *value*. *Values* are the atomic elements under consideration. *Expressions* are a combination of values, functions, and other expressions (or whatever a given grammar allows). All values are expressions.

For the case that I'm interested in, reals are values, and functions are not.

Examples of values: 1, 2, $\pi$
Examples of expressions: 1, 2, $\pi$, $x$, $x + 2$, $y + f(x)$

Expressions can be *evaluated*, resulting in either a value, or a new expression. If we *bind* the value 3 to $x$, for example, we can substitute 3 for $x$ wherever we see it in an expression:

$2 \to 2$
$x \to 3$
$x + 2 \to 3 + 2 \to 5$
$y + f(3)$

If the result of this evaluation is a value, we say that evaluation is *complete*. In some cases, it isn't possible to reduce an expression any further given the existing definitions:

$y + f(x) \to y + f(3)$

Here the result is still an expression. In other cases, evaluation of the expression never terminates. Let $f(x) := g(x)$, $g(x) := h(x)$, $h(x) := f(x)$.

$f(x) \to g(x) \to h(x) \to f(x) \to ...$

I was looking for a definition that meant *an expression that can be evaluated to completion*, i.e. an expression that can be reduced to a value rather than an expression. I believe the appropriate term is a *closed-form expression*.

A *closed-form expression* contains no free (unbound) variables. This means that all of the elements of the expression have been defined, and provided there are no problems with infinite recursion, the expression can evaluated by a Turing machine in a finite number of steps.

A [reference](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dpw/courses/cos326-12/lec/06-evaluation-model.pdf).

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1 e^{-x^2}\,dx$  has no free variables but I think that an explicit integral is not usually called a closed form expression.

Comment: It seems *analytical expression* is slightly more appropriate in this context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Analytic_expression? I think the usage varies in math and CS.